# grub menu not showing in dual boot Linux mint 17 & windows 10

Tags: linux-mint, windows, grub2, dual-boot, grub

I know that this is a common problem but my situation is a bit different. I had a perfectly working Linux Mint 17.2 and Windows 10 in dual boot with grub menu showing and giving me options on what to boot for weeks now, but then I wanted to boot into BIOS but I forgot what key will let me go into the BIOS so I just randomly pressed all the functions keys and something appeared on the screen but it was too fast for me to read then it went into BIOS. I didn't touch anything in the BIOS and after exiting it booted directly into Windows 10 and I haven't booted into Linux ever since.

Things I've tried:

- I tried changing the boot options(F12) but ubuntu wasn't listed there
- Turned off fast boot and hibernate in Windows 10
- bcdedit in windows
- Manually reinstalling grub by following the answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/683108/grub-menu-not-showing-at-boot
- Booted into a live mint 17.2 and did boot-repair

Here is my boot-repair boot info
http://paste2.org/pMP8E2WY

I just remembered after exiting bios and as it booted into windows 10 there were updates so maybe that update could have killed my grub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own problem.

I opened command line in windows as admin and typed this command.
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`. Then shut down not reboot (I don't know if this matters though) then I was welcomed by the very familiar grub menu :)

I swear that I have tried this already but I tried it before I did the boot-repair so maybe that could have been one factor why this time it worked and also maybe shutting down instead of rebooting after the `bcdedit`

Comment: Similarly it's like the solutions presented in in threads such as: https://askubuntu.com/questions/667484/restore-efi-from-windows-after-windows-10-upgade-broke-boot-list

Comment: I know it's not encouraged to write +1 comments, but Sir, you saved me several hours of painstaking search for a solution to this problem. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

For more details check the [articles](http://leopathu.in/content/dual-boot-linux-not-showing-windows-boot-loader-recovering-linux)

**Step to Solve the Problem :**

1. Download & Install the EasyBCD in the windows system
2. Open the EasyBCD after complete the installation process
3. Click Add New Entry from the left bar
4. Choose Linux/BCD tab on the same page and choose the correct version of the linux system
5. Click Add Entry button to save the entry.

Close the application and Reboot the system, The linux would appear in windows boot loader.